# How to test the physical integrity of the internet cable and local ISP devices

Tags: networking, internet, cable

I've been wondering, how can I find out what's the problem with my internet without leaving my home.

I live in a residential building and use cable internet with cable modem, and above the door of every flat there is box.

If someone cut's the cables there or damages the boxes, does the cable modem indicates a physical interruption in the cable?

Or is there a way to ping or use some command to test if the cable is uninterrupted from home to the nearest ISP device(maybe the building broadband device)?

Just are there such ways to become aware of the state of the local internet cable integrity and ISP devices?

What about a way to scan/ping neighborhood modem/routers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the default gateway your cable modem has reliably responds to ping, it is probably sufficient to just ping that.